# How do I solve $(a+b)^4≤8(a^4+b^4)$?

Tags: inequality

$(a+b)^4≤8(a^4+b^4)$ such that $a,b∈\mathbb{R}$

I don't know how to solve that. $\\$
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

It is $$8(a^4+b^4)-(a+b)^4=(a-b)^2 \left(7 a^2+10 a b+7 b^2\right)\geq 0$$

Comment: Is $(a−b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)≥0$ true ?

Comment: Also you should state that $$7a^2+10ab+7b^2=5(a+b)^2+2a^2+2b^2\ge0$$

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Okay i did something like that but i didn't know that was true

Comment: @tkerteg It is much clearer that it's true given my comment as every term is a square.

Comment: Nice. Its easier to see why 7x^2 + 10x + 7 is always positive. Put x = a/b

Answer (score 3):

The function $x^4$ is a convex function. Hence,

$$\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)^4\leq \frac{a^4+b^4}{2}$$

Hope it helps:)